# Rendering HTML in an Android Activity offline

Tags: html, android, android-activity, android-2.2-froyo

I'm working on an RSS reader app for Android.  I have it to where I snag the RSS feed and parse the messages.  When the user touches a title, I pass off the contents of the post to another activity, which displays the contents of the post in a standard text layout.  However, the posts come back with images that are in the form of an `<img>` tag, which is expected since that's what it is in the post.  However, with the text layout, it of course prints out the html, which I don't want.  Really, I want to render that HTML in something like a WebView.

Going to the original post in a WebView is out of the question, as the page takes too long to load on a mobile browser and is slow.  How can I render my custom HTML snippet in a WebView?  If WebViews don't allow that, then what other options do I have for rendering the post's HTML without parsing out all `<img>` (and other) tags and try to download/display them individually?  I'd rather not reinvent a browser control if I can help it.

Here's an example of a post for clarity:

```
<img src="http://myhost.com/myimages/image.jpg"/></br>Here is the content of my article.  Yada Yada.  Etc. Etc.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `WebView.loadData` or `WebView.loadDataWithBaseUrl` ([docs here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)). You'll need to use the `withBaseUrl` version if you're loading any images or javascript from the Web in the WebView, and provide an http(s) url of some sort as the base URL.